# parsing model to a control through a partial View for button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the current model( which is in partial view ) to controller

i use following codes but not working.

```
  var model = function () {
        return @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)); }();


    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("AddSchedule1DynamicRow")",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $(id).append(model);
        attachExpandEvent();
        readonlyControlsSchedule1();
        getDescriptionSchedule1();
    }
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSchedule1DynamicRow([System.Web.Http.FromBody]CITMainReturnModel model)
{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = CTConstants.ScheduleModelName.Schedule1Model;
    //model = new CITSchedule01Model(6);
    if (model.Schedule1Model != null)
    {
        model.Schedule1Model.ListSubSchedule1Model.Add(new CITSubSchedule01Model());
        return PartialView("_Schedule1DynamicList", model);
    }
    return PartialView("_Schedule1DynamicList", new CITSchedule01Model(6));
}
```

Comment: What is the point of posting back exactly the same model that the server sever just sent to the view.

Comment: this is for bind dynamic textbox it is inside _Schedule1DynamicList partial view

Answer (score 0):

**I found A way to do this**

```
$.post(url, $("#MainReturnForm").serialize(), function (res) {
            $(id).append(res);
        });
```

> this was work for me